# What happens to a Kafka consumer group on the Kafka server when the underlying Kafka topic is deleted?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I have the Kafka topic `cars`.

I also have a consumer group `cars-consumers` that is subscribed to the `cars` topic. The `cars-consumers` consumer group is currently at the offset 89.

When I now delete the `cars` topic, what happens to the `cars-consumers` consumer group? Will it also be deleted?

If not, what happens when I re-create a `cars` topic? Will the `cars-consumers` consumer group still be at offset 89?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be immediately deleted.

The `__consumer_offsets` topic maintains the group name as a record key, with topic-partition offsets stored in the values. It will eventually get compacted if there are no commits to the same group.

In other words, if the group is subscribed to `cars` topic and others, then the committed offsets for the `cars` topic will remain as long as commits continue for the other topics (since they are all grouped by the group key). So, if you recreate the topic for a group that has more than just that topic, you might then see old offsets. However, if the offsets are at `89`, as you say, and this is not immediately available on the next consumer poll, then `auto.offset.reset` will take affect, either going to the beginning or end of the topic

Comment: Why exactly does it work, if a consumer is only subscribed to one topic? I can observe the behaviour that there are no commited offets for a CG after deletion of a singular topic, but when and why exactly does the cleanup happen? Compaction does not answer that, as the last state of current offsets/partition will be kept by definition. Only thing I can imagine is that consumers unable to consume a partition will commit this in some way.

Comment: @kopaka Please create a new post to describe your issue in more detail. Number of subscribed topics in a group doesn't matter, for one. Secondly, the log cleaner logic isn't precise, so when/why is hard to answer (other than offsets.retention.ms is triggered)